# Summary of Apple Specfic terminal commands

Tags: macos, terminal

Where can i find such a good list? I tried googling, but they just cover the linux basics (cd, ls, rm, sed, etc.). What are the Apple specific tools for changing settings, volumes, bundles, plists etc?

Comment: @lhf, I thought it would be a dupe too, but could not find one right away, a pretty good excuse to ask the question don't you say? (In short: not a helpful comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `grep -l 'Mac OS X' /usr/share/man/man[18]/*|while read l;do cmd=${l##*/};cmd=${cmd%.[18]};apropos $cmd|grep "^$cmd([18]) ";done|sed 's/([18])  *- / /'`
- http://lri.me/shell.txt
- http://wiki.freegeek.org/index.php/Mac_Commandline_Tools
- https://serverfault.com/questions/7346/what-are-useful-command-line-commands-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 4):

### Online References

Have you looked at [this list](http://ss64.com/osx/)? It seems to provide a pretty good library of OS X commands.

There is also an API Reference of the [Mac OS X Man pages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/) online here if you would like to see all possible commands.

### On your computer

Although this is not a perfect list, you can grep (search) `/usr/share/man` with this line (first `cd /usr/share/man`):

`find man* -type f -print | egrep -v '.gz$' | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 egrep -l 'Mac ?OS ?X'`

(more verbose)

or

`find man* -type f -print | egrep '.gz$' | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0 zegrep -l 'Mac ?OS ?X'`

(less verbose)

Comment: Thank you. Strange i couldn't find it with google, perhaps just the wrong keywords..